# How do you align an image with the top of some text with line height > 1 and allow the text to wrap around it?

Tags: html, css

Given the following markup and css:

```
<p>
   <img src="" width="80" height="200"/>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras rhoncus
     ante in vehicula mollis. Praesent auctor pellentesque erat, et sagittis
     lorem lobortis sed. Nunc mollis pharetra massa, in dictum augue
     fermentum eget. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus aliquet velit in purus
     venenatis, eget tristique lacus eleifend. Proin eget magna mollis,
     venenatis eros eu, semper ante. Suspendisse potenti. Duis vel facilisis
     velit. Donec quis lacus commodo, consectetur tortor vel, venenatis
     nisl. Vestibulum ac nisl non purus consectetur sodales.
</p>

p {
    line-height: 4;
}

img {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

The img correctly aligns to the top of the text, regardless of line-height, but the text does not wrap around the img in the natural way.

If I change the css to this:

```
p {
    line-height: 4;
}

img {
    float: left;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

the text wraps, but the img no longer aligns to the top of the text.

Is there any way of doing this that will allow the img to stay aligned with the top of the text as I change line-height without needing me to change some other property at the same time (such as a negative margin or other such evils)?

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5vk555nm/

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do if your `line-height` is variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not ideal, because it introduces a semantically superfluous extra parent element, but I have a solution. vertical-align: text-top aligns an image to the top of the font of the parent element. By floating the img element itself that context is lost; however, if the img itself is not floated but is inside an element that is both floated and has the same line-height, it aligns to the top of the (theoretical) font in that element and so you get the desired result:

```
<style>
  p {
    line-height: 4;
  }

  span {
    float: left;
  }

  img {
    vertical-align: text-top;
  }
</style>
<p>
  <span><img src="" width="80" height="200"/></span>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras rhoncus
  ante in vehicula mollis. Praesent auctor pellentesque erat, et sagittis
  lorem lobortis sed. Nunc mollis pharetra massa, in dictum augue
  fermentum eget. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus aliquet velit in purus
  venenatis, eget tristique lacus eleifend. Proin eget magna mollis,
  venenatis eros eu, semper ante. Suspendisse potenti. Duis vel facilisis
  velit. Donec quis lacus commodo, consectetur tortor vel, venenatis
  nisl. Vestibulum ac nisl non purus consectetur sodales.
</p>
```

JSFiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/8urdcou0/